# How to pass json data to Vue via html attibute

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to pass json data via html attribute in vue.js.

```html
<div id="app" data-number="2" data-json="{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}"></div>
```

in my main.js file

```js
new Vue({
    el: `#app`,
    render: h => h(App,{
      props:{
        myNumber: this.dataset.number,
        myData: this.dataset.json
      }
    })
  })
```

if I do console log for `console.log(this.dataset.number)` I get 2 which is correct but when I do console log for `myData` I just get `{` and it doesnt get the right json data. Any idea how to pass jason data to vue instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes are the problem. But better bind the varaibles as @Batuhan  has already said correctly.

```
<div id="app" data-number="2" data-json="{'name':'John', 'age':30, 'car':null}"></div>

// or

<div id="app" data-number="2" data-json='{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}'></div>
```

Comment: thanks, the problem was with the quotes. If I do `v-bind:` or `:` I get undefined, not sure why

Answer (score 2):

First one is `binding` data,

```
<div id="app" data-number="2" :data-json="{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}"></div>
```

or

```
<div id="app" data-number="2" v-bind:data-json="{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}"></div>
```

Second one is stringifying the json. You can use `JSON.stringify()` before send it as prop. After that you can parse in component via `JSON.parse()`,

```js
new Vue({
    el: `#app`,
    render: h => h(App,{
      props:{
        myNumber: JSON.stringify(this.dataset.number),
        myData: JSON.stringify(this.dataset.json)
      }
    })
  })
```